# Why is takeWhile returning the empty string when more characters are available?

Tags: haskell

I have a string `r` whose value is below, and I want to extract the string `"index.htm"`.

```
"<a id=\"ctl00_HyperLink_home\" href=\"index.htm\"> " ++
"<font color=\"#FFFFFF\">Home</font>" ++
"</a>"
```

My code is

```
parseHref :: String -> String
parseHref ('h':'r':'e':'f':'=':'\"':xs) =  takeWhile( '\"'>) xs
parseHref (_:xs) = parseHref xs
```

But `parseHref r` is the empty string. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you're writing a parser for educational purposes, you might consider using an HTML parsing library, e.g. tagsoup: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML by hand or even with regexes is highly error–prone. Consider using a library such as [TagSoup](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup).

A first cut looks like

```
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

ctl00_HyperLink_home_url s =
  map (fromAttrib "href") $
  filter (~== "<a id=ctl00_HyperLink_home href=''>") $
  parseTags s
```

It has type `String -> [String]`, so the interface is a bit klunky.

Adding some flexibility to the interface gives

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Control.Monad (MonadPlus(..))
import Text.HTML.TagSoup

ctl00_HyperLink_home_url :: (MonadPlus m) => String -> m String
ctl00_HyperLink_home_url (anchors -> tags) = popSome tags
  where popSome []    = mzero
        popSome (t:_) = return $ fromAttrib "href" t

anchors :: String -> [Tag String]
anchors = filter (~== "<a id=ctl00_HyperLink_home href=''>") . parseTags
```

In action, this looks like

```
ghci> ctl00_HyperLink_home_url r :: Maybe String
Just "index.htm"
ghci> ctl00_HyperLink_home_url r :: [String]
["index.htm"]
ghci> ctl00_HyperLink_home_url "x" :: Maybe String
Nothing
ghci> ctl00_HyperLink_home_url "x" :: [String]
[]
```

With [Control.Monad.STM](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stm-2.1.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-STM.html) in scope, we can

```
ghci> atomically $ ctl00_HyperLink_home_url r
"index.htm"
```

To extract the inner text also, we need more than the open tag. Assuming the argument contains the anchor tag and children only, you might borrow from [“Drinking TagSoup By Example”](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.6/src/tagsoup.htm) and write

```
ctl00 :: String -> (String,String)
ctl00 html =
  let as = head $
           sections (~== "<a id='ctl00_HyperLink_home' href=''") $
           parseTags html
      text = unwords . words . innerText
  in (fromAttrib "href" $ head as, text as)
```

In action:

```
ghci> ctl00 r
("index.htm","Home")
```

Multiple applications of the partial function `head` is worrisome. Let’s put it back inside `MonadPlus`, observing the convention of appending a capital M at the end to signify monadic goodness.

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Control.Monad
import Data.List (foldl')

ctl00M :: (MonadPlus m) => String -> m (String, String)
ctl00M = foldl' mplus mzero
       . map (return . (fromAttrib "href" . head &&& text))
       . sections (~== "<a id='ctl00_HyperLink_home' href=''")
       . parseTags
  where text = unwords . words . innerText
```

Finally, for a general function whose application gives a dictionary whose keys are control identifiers and whose values are pairs of the form (*url*, *inner–text*) use

```
controls :: String -> Map String (String,String)
controls = fromList
         . concatMap idHrefText
         . sections (~== "<a id='' href=''>")
         . parseTags
  where
    idHrefText (a:tags)
      | isControl a = [(ctlId a, (href a, text tags))]
      | otherwise   = []
    isControl = ("ctl" `isPrefixOf`) . ctlId
    ctlId = fromAttrib "id"
    href = fromAttrib "href"
    text tags = let (a,_) = break (~== "</a>") tags
                    extract =  unwords . words . innerText
                in extract a
```

Breaking on `</a>` is an attempt to avoid grabbing too much text.

For example

```
ghci> (controls r) ! "ctl00_HyperLink_home"
("index.htm","Home")
```

Comment: very good example for tagsoup; what I have to do if I want to get the value <a..>..Value..</a>, in this case "Home". There may be font tag/other tags or it does not contain any other tag.

Comment: may be I need to use fromtagtext but can't correctly use it> :(

Answer (score 8):

`"` is ASCII 32
`i` is ASCII 105

since `"` is not greater than `i`, so takeWhile takes nothing and returns an empty string.

perhaps you should use `('\"' /=)`?

Answer (score 3):

1) You should use `'"'` insead of `'\"'`

2) Your function miss empty list `[]` case, for example

```
parseHref [] = []
```

3) condition in `takeWhile` is wrong. You wish to stop when exactly find `'"'`, so `('"' /=)` - right condition

4) Maybe you should use `Maybe String` to indicate failing:

```
parseHref :: String -> Maybe String
parseHref [] = Nothing
parseHref ('h':'r':'e':'f':'=':'"':xs) =  Just $ takeWhile ('"' /=) xs
parseHref (_:xs) = parseHref xs
```